# linear combination of colors in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to help a student with a NetLogo homework. The gist of the homework is to load images, save the patch values to properties `c1 c2` for each patch, set an alpha value `0.0 <= alpha <=1.0` and then set the patches to a linear combination of `c1` and `c2` under `alpha`.

This ought to be simple: all I want to do is code (this is pseudocode, I know this doesn't actually work) like:

```
to combine
  ask patches [ set pcolor (c1 * alpha) + (c2 * alpha) ]
end
```

the problem being that `c1`,`c2` are vectors, `alpha` is a scalar, and I can't figure out how to do vector multiply and vector addition in NetLogo.

Here's the code to set up a test case:

```
patches-own [ c1 c2]
to setup
  ask patches [ set pcolor one-of [ red green blue] ]
end

to load-image
  import-pcolors image
end

to set-one
  ask patches [ set c1 pcolor ]
end

to set-two
  ask patches [ set c2 pcolor ]
end

to return-c1
  ask patches [ set pcolor c1 ]
end
```

Comment: can you provide some sample data so we know what c1 and c2 look like? are they always same length vectors?

Comment: The image is a single arena with one set of patches, and c1,c2 are individual values of color for each patch. pcolors are defined as 3 element lists so they are indeed the same length.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your various vectors (or lists really in NetLogo) and other numbers look like. But if the heart of the problem is that you want to multiply a 'vector' and scalar, here is a function that does so:

```
to-report mult-vec-num [ #vec #num ]
  report map [ ii -> ii * #num] #vec
end
```

The `map` primitive is essentially an implicit foreach, with the arbitrarily named ii being used as an iterator through the provided list (named #vec) and multiplied by the provided scalar (named #num). Example use case:

```
show mult-vec-num [ 1 2 3 ] 5
```

UPDATE:

To add two lists together, again use the `map` primitive:

```
let l1 [1 2 3]
let l2 [4 5 6]
show (map + l1 l2)
```

Comment: c1 and c2 are pcolors, 3 element rgb lists.

Comment: okay, i have extended the answer to also show addition of lists of numbers